# Postfix null-client doesn't deliver mail to my domain

Tags: postfix, null-client

1) I'm using mail from Yandex for mydomain.com

DNS MX record is:
`mydomain.com.   21599  IN  MX  10 mx.yandex.net.`

All works fine.

2) I need send notification emails directly from my server. 
I installed Postfix as null-client with config:

```
myorigin = mydomain.com
myhostname = mydomain.com
mydestination =
#relayhost = 
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

When I send emails from server to another domains - all works fine, but email sended to my domain like **user@mydomain.com** doesn't send and I got line in logs:

> Feb 11 19:37:49 myhost postfix/smtp[7551]: 69BDA5AEBF:
>   to=**user@mydomain.com**, relay=none, delay=998, delays=998/0.02/0/0,
>   dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   **mail.mydomain.com**[my.server.ip.address]:25: Connection refused)

I don't understand, why postfix trying to connect `mail.mydomain.com` instead `mx.yandex.net`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I opened the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and checked each of the ip addresses with `dig mx mydomain.com @IP_ADRESS`

One of them apparently has not yet been updated and contained an old DNS record, because of which the Postfix worked incorrectly.